# Cannot be able to access my website hosted on my mac through another PC on different Internet

Tags: networking, router, dns, apache-http-server, website

I am trying to make my machine a web server so that I can host websites on my laptop and anyone sitting anywhere can access it. The problem I am having is The website can be accessed on the same wifi network but not when it's been accessed from the different network.

What I have done so far is this

1. First I find out what my router ip is by typing into terminal `ipconfig`

   `192.168.10.1` //through this I can access the router panel.

my localhost ip is

```
  192.168.10.2
```

Since I have installed xampp in my mac. I can successfully see the page either typing localhost or this `192.168.10.2` if I am using different machine connected to the same network

I also went to my router panel and added DMZ host
[image]

and also did this

[image]

Then I have also registered and downloaded the https://www.noip.com/ and start it. So now everything works fine as long as I am connected to the same network. if I type 192.168.10.2 or my dynamic ip(119.152.134.xxx) or nop-ip domain. everything works but on same network not different. 
what I am missing now. Why its not working on different network?

Comment: It's not accessible from a different network because it hasn't been published. As it sits, it's an intranet website and not an internet one. You may want to purchase a domain or a static address and then configure your server to publish it. Right now it cannot be accessed from a foreign network.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add your credentials for noip.com in your router settings so that the router is able to report its external ip.

Since it looks you have configured the DMZ, you should be able to access your web service from outside your local network. What you need to know is your external IP.

Try typing "what is my ip address" in a google search. You will get your external IP address and you can try to access your web service using a URL like this:

```
http://<external_ip_address>/
```